# if linear map onto itself is bijective given that it is injective?

Tags: linear-algebra

If given $l \in L(V)$ is injective then can we say that it is bijective too?
My reasoning:
by rank nullity theorem $N(l) = \{0\}$, implies $dim(R(l)) = dim(V)$, so $l$ is also surjective

Comment: If $\dim V$ is finite, that is correct.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $dim V$ is finite in this case but what happens when it is not finite?

Comment: If $V$ is infinite-dimensional, the result doesn't hold (in general). For example, if $V$ is the vector space of all real sequences $(x_1,x_2,x_3\dots)$, consider the operator $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ given by $T(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots) = (0,x_1,x_2,\dots)$. As $T(x_1,x_2,x_3\dots) = (0,0,0,\dots)$ implies $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots) = (0,0,0,\dots)$ we have that $T$ is injective. But $T$ is not surjective since $(1,0,0,\dots)$ is not in the image of $T$.

Comment: It does not work in general for the infinite dimensional case. For instance, let $V$ be the set of all sequences $a:\mathbb N \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ (or whatever field you're working in). Let $l(a)_0 = 0$ and $l(a)_n = a_{n - 1}$ for $n \geq 1$. This essentially shifts a sequence to the right one step. It is injective but not onto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a provable theorem that a linear map $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ is injective if and only if it is surjective, provided that $V$ is finite-dimensional. The argument is almost exactly as you suggested:

\begin{align*}
\text{$T$ is injective } & \iff \text{Null}(T) = \{0\} \\
& \iff \dim V = \dim \text{Null}(T) + \dim \text{Range}(T) = \dim \text{Range}(T) \\
& \iff \text{Range}(T) = V.
\end{align*}
The third line follows from the second since $\text{Range}(T)$ is a subspace of $V$, so if $\dim V = \dim \text{Range}(T)$, we have $V = \text{Range}(T)$.

This result doesn't generalize to the infinite case. Notice that we used the rank-nullity theorem in the second line, which requires that $\dim V$ be finite.